# How to select an <option> within a <select> tag using Selenium in Python 3?

Tags: python, html, selenium, webdriver, frame

new to Python here so thanks in advance and sorry if I say something really basically obvious.

The option I want to click on is quite nested (don't know if it makes a difference, it might since I'm pretty ignorant in the subject). The nesting goes:

```
<frameset <frame <html <body <form <table <tbody <tr <td <p <select <option
```

The select has name='base' and size=15, thats it.
The option has value='B101' and Text='Cam'

Here is what I have:

```py
table = driver.find_element_by_name('base')
         for option in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
             if option.text == 'Cam':
                 option.click()
                 break`
```

But is breaks at the first line, with this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="base"]"}
```

Also tried using the xpath but i get this: `/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input`, (instead of what I am used to something like `//*[@id=...`) and it doesn't find it either. Not by class 'select'.

Also tried going directly to the option by xpath, name, class, nothing works.
I just cannot seem to click the option. Don't know if it makes a difference here but I'm on a mac and using ChromeDriverManager.
After clicking the option I have to click on 'Select' to go to the next page.

EDIT:
Thanks Shreyas! Excuse my ignorance, I did that, and it does not bring an error, but nor do I see the option selected. After clicking on the option I would have to click on a 'Select' button (tag 'input'), which I also cannot find with Selenium. Here is the HTML in case it helps:

```
<frameset rows="40,*,25" frameborder="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame name="Results" src="/documents/bases.jsp" marginwidth="3" marginheight="3">
        #document
            <html><head><title>Base</title>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Wed, 26 Feb 1997">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" marginwidth="3" marginheight="3">
<form method="POST" action="/documents/bases.jsp">
<input type="hidden" name="tdb" value="B">
<table align="center" border="0">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td valign="top"><img src="/images/bases.jpg" width="30" height="28"></td>
        <td>
            <p align="center"><font color="#804040" size="4" face="Verdana"><b>
            Available Base
            </b></font></p>
            <p align="center">
            <select name="base" size="15" multiple="">
<option value="B096">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B101">This_option</option>
<option value="B109">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B110">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B151">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B158">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B170">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B219">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B221">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B222">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B223">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B261">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B300">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B351">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B352">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B502">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B511">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B649">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B650">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B660">Not_this_option</option>
<option value="B704">Not_this_option</option>
            </select>
            </p>
        </td>
        <!--
        <td align='center' valign='top'>
            <table border='1'>
                <tr>
                    <td align='center'>
                        <font size='2'><b>What kind<br>
                        Of base do you wanna see?</b></font><p>
                        <a href='bases.jsp?tdb=B' target='Results'>Kind1/a><br>
                        <a href='bases.jsp?tdb=F' target='Results'>Kind2</a></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center">
            <input type="submit" name="Select" value="Select">
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
</form>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. First find the value of the option element you want to select.
2. Then you can run javascript to change the value of the select element.

```
value = "B101"
driver.execute_script('var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
                      for (element of elements) {
                        element.value = ' + value + '
                      }')
```

`document.getElementByTagNames('select')` gets all the elements with the select tag and returns an array of all those elements

Then, we loop through each element in the elements list and change the value of the select tag to your desired value.

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT!
Since the HTML has frames, first you have to switch to the correct frame:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name('Results'))
Option = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'This_option')]")
Option.click()
Select = driver.find_element_by_name('Select')
Select.click()
```